# The union of a collection of open sets is open

Tags: general-topology

My attempt: Say $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ is a collection of open sets. If we can show that $\operatorname{Int}(\bigcup A_{\alpha}) =  \bigcup A_{\alpha}$, then we are done. We know the interior of any set is inside the set, so we must check the other inclusion. So, take 
$$x \in \bigcup A_{\alpha} \implies x \in A_{\alpha}$$ for some $\alpha$

and so since $A_{\alpha}$ is open, then there exists a neighborhood of $x$, $N_{\alpha}$, such that $N_{\alpha} \subseteq A_{\alpha}$. Therefore, $N_{\alpha} \subseteq \bigcup A_{\alpha}$. Hence, by definition, $x$ must lie inside $\operatorname{Int}(\bigcup A_{\alpha})$

Is this proof correct? can you guys give me some feedback?

Comment: Usually this fact is part of the **definition** of *open set*. What definition of *open set* are you using?

Comment: a set $A$ is open if there exists a nghbd N of a point $x \in A$ so that $N$ lies inside $A$

Comment: The proof, given the definition, is correct. But I am for sure not fond of the definition!

Comment: That simply pushes back the question by one remove. For many of us *nbhd of* $x$ simply means *open set containing* $x$. What is your definition of *nbhd of* $x$? (Your proof is almost certainly correct, given that definition of *open set*, but I’m still curious.)

Comment: It also raises the question of what you mean by interior.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  No matter what weird notion of "neighborhood" you use, if you then define "$U$ is open" to mean that every $x\in U$ has a neighborhood that is $\subseteq U$, then the union of any family of open sets will be open.

Comment: @Andreas: *Almost certainly* was to cover the thoroughly unlikely possibility that the OP was somehow misusing whatever definition of *interior* was on offer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Right. I didn't intend to claim that the OP's argument is right independently of the notion of neighborhood, only that the result is provable independently of the notion of neighborhood.

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof does not make sense if you took the definition of a topology as a collection of subsets closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions, so I assume that you are given for each point $x\in X$ a filter base $\mathcal B_x$ of sets containing $x$ satisfying the condition

> For each $B\in\mathcal B_x$ there is an $C\in\mathcal B_x$ such that for each $y\in C$ there is a $D\in\mathcal B_y,\ D\subseteq B$. $\ (*)$

If you then define an open set $O$ as a set which for each of its points $x\in O$ contains a set from the corresponding filter base $\mathcal B_x$, this will give you a topology and then your proof is correct.

The property $(*)$ is not needed here. It just makes sure that if you define the topology via these filter bases, then this topology will have the generated filters as neighborhoods.